# Making an NSAlert be displayed when the User attempts to delete a row from an NSOutlineView when it has children

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How would I do this?
The Outline View is being used with Core Data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This hasn't really got anything to do with Core Data. Just check [object.children count] upon deletion. When it is not 0, show a NSAlert.

Comment: I had a go at it bearing in mind what you said. Here's what happened - http://snapplr.com/hx7s.

Comment: That's because `selectedRow` is just a number, not the underlying row object, so it doesn't respond to the `children` message.

Comment: Oh, I see. How would I get the underlying row object?

Comment: I had a go at getting the underlying row object using this code. http://snapplr.com/xae4. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Joshua: You need `selectedRow` to be the model object for what the user has selected. You know, the object with the `children` property.

Comment: Whats the the model object for what the user has selected?